# Android app for encoding number to alphabet codes

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android programming. I have a set of predefined values like  `A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 .....J=0`. After this I want to add two numbers for examples `365+654= 1019` and I want to show this result in form of those alphabet characters that has been defined  i.e "`AJAI`".

What is the proper way and logic for this? I have searched a lot but couldn't get lucky enough.

Comment: I mean, it's not like you couldn't put the letters in an array at the correct indices, or that methods exist to convert a number to a String, or to split the string into individual characters, and using those individual characters as numbers to access the letters in the array.

Comment: Thank you AntonH.. could you please give me a example code to do this.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) As written, you're basically asking us to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: You should learn some Java, because this seems not so hard ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works just fine:

```
public class TEST{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(getWordByNumber(1091));
 }

 private static String[] letters = {"J", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"};
 private String  getWordByNumber(int number){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     while (number > 0) {
         sb.append( letters[number % 10]);
         number = number / 10;
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

}

Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you @Mett.. it works like a charm. I got the result but it's in reverse order. I shall work to order it properly...